# Angularjs $http get not working

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am trying to access REST web service from angularjs. I am not able to call it successfully.

AngularJs Code

```
var singleOrderUrl = "/singleOrder/retrieve";
function getSingleOrderDetails(userName,singleOrderUrl,$http,$q) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        var deffered = $q.defer();
        fd.append('USERNAME', 'test123');
        //fd.append();
        //fd.append();
        console.log("inside service"+userName+"singleOrderUrl:::"+singleOrderUrl);
        return $http.get(singleOrderUrl, fd, {
            withCredentials : false,
            transformRequest : angular.identity,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined,
            }

        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);              
            responseData = response.data.toString();;               
            deffered.resolve(response);             
            return responseData;
        }).error(function(error) {
            alert("error");
            deffered.reject(error);
            return "failed";
        });
        };
```

Rest Service code

@RestController
public class SingleOrderHistoryController {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SingleOrderHistoryController.class.getName()); 

@RequestMapping(value = "/singleOrder/retrieve", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public List<SingleHistoryRecord> getSingleOrderDetails(@RequestParam(value = Constants.USER_NAME, required = true) String userName, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    logger.debug("inside SingleOrderHistoryController ");   
    List<SingleHistoryRecord> singleOrderHistoryList = new ArrayList<SingleHistoryRecord>();        
    SingleHistoryRecord record1 = new SingleHistoryRecord();
    SingleHistoryRecord record2 = new SingleHistoryRecord();

    record1.setClientIdentifier(userName);
    record1.setSubmitDate("01/05/2017");
    record1.setStatus("Complete");
    record1.setReferenceID("1234555");
    record1.setOrderID("test123");
    record2.setClientIdentifier(userName);
    record2.setSubmitDate("01/05/2017");
    record2.setStatus("Complete");
    record2.setReferenceID("1234555");
    record2.setOrderID("test123");      
    singleOrderHistoryList.add(record1);
    singleOrderHistoryList.add(record2);

    return singleOrderHistoryList;
}
```

Can anyone please advise what I am doing wrong here, It is getting the source code of the page in response instead of getting the list.

Comment: 1. youre not using deferred correctly.
2. where are you getting the source code back. 3. Try to get data back from your api outside the app using postman or some other rest client.

Comment: I have tried accessing Rest through soapUI and its working fine. The value of response is the page source code of the page.

Comment: http.get only accepts 2 paramaters. the url and a config option. you have 3 if your trying to send data to your api you will need use post.

Comment: can you provide the response?

Comment: Angular version matters. The .success(..).error(..) is deprecated (and now quite old) so I'm guessing you are using a more modern angular version (somewhere after 1.3 I think?) So you should use `$http.get(...).then( successHandler, errorHandler);`